# In Qt, how to show keyboard shortcuts in menu but disable them?

Tags: qt, qt4, menu, keyboard-shortcuts, pyqt

I'm adding a bunch of `QAction`s to my main window's menus. These actions can also be triggered by the keyboard, and I want the shortcut to be visible in the menu, as usual, e.g.

```
-----------------
|Copy     Ctrl+C|
-----------------
```

I can do this using `QAction.setShortcut()`. However, I **don't** want these `QAction`s to be triggered by the shortcuts; I'm handling all keyboard input separately elsewhere.

Is this possible? Can I disable the shortcut in the QAction but still have the shortcut text (in this example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) in my menus?

**EDIT**: The way I ended up doing it is connecting to the menu's `aboutToShow()` and `aboutToHide()` events, and enabling/disabling the shortcuts so they are only active when the menu is shown. But I'd appreciate a cleaner solution...

Comment: Just for interest's sake, why are you handling all keyboard input somewhere else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could inherit from QAction and override QAction::event(QEvent*):

```
class TriggerlessShortcutAction : public QAction
{
public:
    ...ctors...

protected:
    virtual bool event(QEvent* e)
    {
        if (e->type() == QEvent::Shortcut)
            return true;
        else
            return QAction::event(e);
    }
};
```

This will cause any events of type QEvent::Shortcut sent to your actions to not trigger the 'triggered()' signals.

Comment: Or, even better, use an event filter instead of subclassing.

Comment: Unfortunately neither the subclass nor the event filter are working for me; the QAction is not receiving a QShortcutEvent. It may be an interaction with some other part of the program, I'll try to find out. In the mean time I'm back to my original solution...

Comment: I tested it on Windows and it worked. maybe try doing it in a new project, it might be a platform issue...

Comment: I'm trying it on a mac -- it must be either a platform issue or something else in my program. Thanks though!

Comment: I've seen some inconsistencies between the platforms in this behaviour - see my comment on http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-12495. Could this be relevant?

Answer (score 6):

```
action.setText("Copy\tCtrl+C");
```

This will look like an action with a shortcut, but the shortcut is not actually installed.

Here is a full example:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow win;

    QMenu *menu = win.menuBar()->addMenu("Test");

    // This action will show Ctrl+T but will not trigger when Ctrl+T is typed.
    QAction *testAction = new QAction("Test\tCtrl+T", &win);
    app.connect(testAction, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), SLOT(quit()));
    menu->addAction(testAction);

    // This action will show Ctrl+K and will trigger when Ctrl+K is typed.
    QAction *quitAction = new QAction("Quit", &win);
    quitAction->setShortcut(Qt::ControlModifier + Qt::Key_K);
    app.connect(quitAction, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), SLOT(quit()));
    menu->addAction(quitAction);

    win.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: This does, in fact, install the shortcut (Qt 4.6, mac)

Comment: With the above example, does Ctrl+T quit the application on a Mac? With Qt 4.6 on Windows and Linux, Ctrl+T does not trigger the action.

Comment: @dF I tested this on WIndows 10, Qt 5.11.2 and this does NOT install the shortcut.